# TYPO3 installation issue - FIRST_INSTALL

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Hi I'm new to TYPO3 and have followed the installation instructions and my installation is stuck at the following point;

> CMS 8.7.0 Thank you for downloading TYPO3
>
> To proceed with the installation, create the file FIRST_INSTALL in
>   your root directory. The filename is case-sensitive but the file
>   itself can be empty.
>
> Note: The file will be deleted once you proceed with the installation.

I have added the file and till the installation shows the same message, please check my server directory included as an image.

thank you.

[[image]]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uudx4.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the file `FIRST_INSTALL` into your DocRoot folder, which seems to be one folder up.
The file shouldn't be situated in the typo3 folder.

Comment: Hi i have tried that and have just moved the file but still i get the same message. see image just added to original post.

Comment: Sorry the link above shows my current folder structure.

Comment: no matter where i place the file the same message appears, very frustrating! any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: v9 says "To begin the installation, create an empty file called FIRST_INSTALL in the document root of your web server." but you need to put it into the root of your typo3 folder. that works for me

Comment: The code says it looks into the "public path", that means the document root. Maybe your configuration misses the definition of the document root? Did you set it into composer.json?

Answer (score 0):

Set chmod 777 or r+w+x on FIRST_INSTALL and sometimes you have to write something in this file, because in some cases empty files are ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Some TYPO3 CMS Installation steps might be help you.

- make sure your root directory has complete access right.
- Basice configuration for the php.
- Create FIRST_INSTALL (must be empty. in your case it seems not empty.) as well as typo3_src file in the root of directory.
- That is enogh for typo3. But, if you field installation please use fresh TYPO3 package for re-installation.

Your fresher file structure should be something like this:
Url: http://localhost/typo/

```
- typo
   |--- Vendor
   |--- typo3
   |--- typo3_src
   |--- FIRST_INSTALL
   |--- index.php
   |--- _htaccess
   |--- composer.lock
   |--- composer.json
   |--- CONTRIBUTING.md
   |--- CONTRIBUTING.md
   |--- INSTALL.md
   |--- LICENSE.txt
```

This is the simple ready to install setup directory. here, 'typo' is the name of root directory. Hope this will help you.

**Ref. link for TYPO3 Installation:** https://www.pagemachine.de/blog/install-typo3-7-lts-local-test-system-windows-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you  decided t0 do a fresh install and i still get the same issue i'm now trying version 7.6.18 my folder structure ha the following in it from the zip file.

Comment: wwwroot (everything is in this folder)  
typo3 (folder)  
vendor (folder)  
_htaccess  
ChangeLog  
composer.json  
composer.lock  
CONTRIBUTING.md  
FIRST_INSTALL  
index.php  
INSTALL.md  
LICENCE.txt  
README.md  
web.config