# Unable to install TYPO3 10 on xampp

Tags: xampp, typo3, typo3-10.x

I want to install TYPO3 CMS v10, but I don't know why the FIRST_INSTALL file is ignored.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: we need some more information from you. Where is your project stored? under htdocs? the FIRST_INSTALL file has to be on the rootpage of your project, at the same directory with index.php

Comment: This is not a programming question, and we are not tech support for Typo3

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the installation instructions from the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/QuickInstall/TheInstallTool/Index.html?highlight=first_install)?

It's important to create the `FIRST_INSTALL` file in your web root directory (e.g. the `public` folder).

And make sure that the file has no suffix such as .txt. Windows tends to attach a suffix to files.

Maybe this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493307/typo3-installation-issue-first-install) gives you some more hints.